# Has anybody ever successfully downloaded the Cities project in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

As shown in the following link, the developer says that the whole project codes are included in the zip archive, but after I downloaded and decompressed it, I can't find the file of Cities.nlogo which is the main procedure for the entire simulation project. I don't know if there are someone else encounter the same problem as mine, how do you solve it ?

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/cities/citiesmodel.shtml#download

Answer (score 0):

I tried this just now:

```
% curl -OsS 'http://ccl.northwestern.edu/cities/cities.zip'
% unzip -l cities.zip | grep Cities.nlogo
error [cities.zip]:  missing 2 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
    36365  09-26-07 15:21   cities/Cities.nlogo
```

as you can see there is definitely a `Cities.nlogo` file in there, but is also appears that the zip file is slightly corrupted ("missing 2 bytes in zipfile"). You might try extracting the archive with a different program? It extracted successfully for me using Archive Utility on Mac OS X.